# Select cases in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, seq

I want to select a range of cases in a data frame, every N column. I will illustrate my problem with a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(100)
data <- data.frame(replicate(18,sample(0:100,18,rep=TRUE)))
```

From data, I want to select `data[1:6, 1]`, then `data[7:12, 7]`, then `data[13:19, 13]`, and so forth. Obviously, I'm working with a bigger dataset (>10000 rows and columns), which is why I would prefer an automated way to do this.
I have tried to define a sequence beforehand (`seq()`) but couldn't quite figure out how to apply it to this problem.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you selecting a subset at a time, performing operations on the subset, then continuing to the next? Or are you trying to select all of these subsets at once and process them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix` indexing might be handy here:

```
sel <- cbind(sequence(nrow(data)),rep(seq(1,ncol(data),6),each=6))
sel

#      row  col
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# ...
# [6,]    6    1
# [7,]    7    7
# ...
#[12,]   12    7
#[13,]   13   13
# ...
```

Then:

```
data[sel]
# [1] 31 26 55  5 47 48 97  3 92 73 20 84 37 30 55 37 85 62
```

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, it's unclear whether you want a single subset at a time or if you want all subsets at once. I'll cover both cases.

One subset at a time:

```
sub <- seq(1, 13, 6)

for (i in seq_along(sub)) {
    data.sub <- data[sub[i]:sub[i+1], sub[i]]

    # Do whatever you need to do with this subset
}
```

All subsets at once:

```
sub <- seq(1, 13, 6)

data.sub <- list()

for (i in seq_along(sub))
    data.sub[[i]] <- data[sub[i]:sub[i+1], sub[i]]

data.sub <- unlist(data.sub)

# Process this vector all at once
```